# PHP scripts stops

Tags: php

I am working with several different php pages and php scripts.

For example I have the page index.php

The user can click on the link script_page.php?id=415354 on the index.php page, and the script_page.php page will check for the id and using some other scripts to verify access it will forward to employees.php using:

```
die(header("Location: employees.php"));
```

Sometimes if I click too fast or click twice, the script_page.php will stop running and never make it to employees.php

What could cause this to be happening or how could I prevent this from happening?

Thank you for your assistance.

I am using IIS7 and PHP5

Comment: Not the solution to your problem, but you should change the code to `header("Location: employees.php"); die();` the form you use doesn't make sense, as `header()` won't return a value.

Comment: When you say "too fast", do you literally mean you click _too fast_ on the `script_page.php?id=415354` link?! How do you know script_page.php _stops_ running? Are you sure it's even getting to script_page.php? Is it possible the request is being cancelled?

Comment: That's a good question.  My browser stops at: www.my-site.com/script_page.php?id=415354.  It's a blank page.  I am not really sure what is happening.

Comment: All browsers? Have you checked your server error logs?

Answer (score 1):

Try separating those two commands:

```
header("Location: employees.php");
die();
```

Comment: Thanks poke, I really appreciate your help.  I separated the header and die functions.  If I click really fast I can get the script_page.php to stop and not execute anything.  It only seems to happen in Firefox.